# Include www prefix in site URL

Tags: multisite, site-url

I'm setting up my first wordpress site (on a WP Multisite server).  In the 'sites'  info page I am asked to enter the site URL.

Should I use 'www.mydomain.com' or 'mydomain.com' ?  (Does it matter?)  I have both addresses resolving to the same IP in the DNS server.  I'm just not sure if WordPress cares or will operate correctly.

Comment: My personal recommendation would be `mydomain.com` is enough. Why should I put some extra 3 characters in the URL? But make sure, the site can be easily visited with or without `www`. In multisite, changing URL in the Settings > General isn't everything. You have to change your `.htaccess`, `wp-config.php` if necessary. So make a backup first.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the full URL of your site, as in https://www.example.com .

If you don't include the protocol (the "https://" part), then pages on your site (and links to other pages or media) won't work properly.